# how to get value from textformfield which is inside a loop

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textformfield

this is snippet code of function in which I use TextFormField inside ListView.builder. Some context here: I'm having objects with empty String poperty, the intention is to make user write in the TextFormField and get that value to work with it.
This is my first time working with TextFormField inside a loop.
Any help guys ?

```
    class AnswerQuizPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnswerQuizPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AnswerQuizPage> createState() => _AnswerQuizPageState();
}

class _AnswerQuizPageState extends State<AnswerQuizPage> {
  int? _numPages ;
  int _currentPage = 1;
  bool test=false;
  var questionController= QuestionController(QuestionRepositoryImpl());
  List<String> reponse=[];
  List<String> asnwers=[];
  List<TextEditingController>_reponse=[];
  List<TextEditingController> _controllers = [];
  List<QuestionModel> listofquestion=[];
  List<QuizQuestion> listofquizquestionsforquiz=GlobalParams.quizmodel.quizQuestions;
  @override
  List<dynamic> trList=[];
  GlobalKey<FormState> globalFormKey=GlobalKey<FormState>();
  void initState(){
    super.initState();

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(GlobalParams.quizmodel.id);
    Future<List<QuestionModel>> quizlist=questionController.getQuestionsByQuizId(GlobalParams.quizmodel.id);
    quizlist.then((value)  {
      //_numPages=value.length-2;
      listofquestion=value;
    });
    /*if (GlobalParams.model.name=="essai"){
      Future<List<QuestionModel>> quizlist=questionController.getQuestionsByQuizId(1);
      quizlist.then((value)  {
        //_numPages=value.length-2;
        listofquestion=value;
      });
    }
    if (GlobalParams.model.name=="spiderman concentration quiz"){
      Future<List<QuestionModel>> quizlist=questionController.getQuestionsByQuizId(2);
      quizlist.then((value)  {
        //_numPages=value.length-2;
        listofquestion=value;
      });
    }*/
   /* Future<List<QuestionModel>> quizlist=questionController.getQuestionsByQuizId(GlobalParams.quizmodel.id);
    quizlist.then((value)  {
      //_numPages=value.length-2;
      listofquestion=value;
    });*/
    _numPages=listofquestion.length;
    //print(listofquestion);
    int? idtochoose;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        title:Text('répondre au quiz'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          //login
          Container(

            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              //color: Colors.orange[600],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0, top:5.0, bottom: 5.0,),
            child: Tooltip(
              message: "vous devez finir le quiz",
              child: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
            ),
            /*IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, auto, auto, bottom)
              tooltip: 'Show Snackbar',
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/superadminhomepage");
              },
            ),*/
          ),


        ],

      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(50),
        child: FutureBuilder<List<QuestionModel>>(
    future:questionController.getQuestionsByQuizId(GlobalParams.quizmodel.id),
    builder:(context ,snapshot){
    if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting){
    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
    }
    if (snapshot.hasError){
    print('${snapshot.error}');
    print('${snapshot}');

    return Center(child: Text('${snapshot}'),);
    }
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(child: buildBodyContent(snapshot, questionController)),
        SizedBox(height: 50,),
        Container(
          child: FormHelper.submitButton("Ajouter", () async{
//QuizModel quiz=QuizModel(id: id, name: name, score: score, quizCategoryEnum: quizCategoryEnum, quizQuestions: quizQuestions, satisfactions: satisfactions, user: user, admin: admin, level: level, quizCategory: quizCategory)

            //print(modelcquuuiz);
            // print (catquizlist.then((value) => value.length));
            // print(code);
            // print(libelle);
            //    print("tr is   +++   " + tr!);
            /* if (validateAndSave()){

                              setState(() {
                                isAPIcallProcess=true;
                              });
                              ThemeModel model= ThemeModel.addTheme(libelle: libelle!, code: code!, tr: tr!);
                              themeController.postTheme(model, jwt!.id).then((response) {
                                setState(() {

                                  isAPIcallProcess=false;
                                });
                               // if (response.isNotEmpty){
                                  print(response);
                                  FormHelper.showSimpleAlertDialog(
                                    context,
                                    Config.appName,
                                    "Ajout avec succès",
                                    "D\'accord",
                                        (){
                                      //  Navigator.pop(context);
                                      /* Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context,
                                '/signin', (route) => false);*/
                                      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                                          context,
                                          "/thememanagementpage",
                                              (route) => false);
                                    },
                                  );
                             //   }
                                /*else {
                                  print(response);
                                  FormHelper.showSimpleAlertDialog(
                                    context,
                                    Config.appName,
                                    "erreur d'ajout ",
                                    "D\'accord",
                                        (){
                                      //  Navigator.pop(context);
                                      /* Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context,
                                '/signin', (route) => false);*/
                                      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                                          context,
                                          "/thememanagementpage",
                                              (route) => false);
                                    },
                                  );
                                }*/
                              });
                            }
                            else {
                             // print(response);
                              FormHelper.showSimpleAlertDialog(
                                context,
                                Config.appName,
                                "erreur d'ajout ",
                                "D\'accord",
                                    (){
                                  //  Navigator.pop(context);
                                  /* Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context,
                                '/signin', (route) => false);*/
                                  Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                                      context,
                                      "/thememanagementpage",
                                          (route) => false);
                                },
                              );
                            }*/

            /* if (validateAndSave()){

                              setState(() {
                                isAPIcallProcess=true;
                              });
                              RegisterRequestModel model=RegisterRequestModel(
                                  username: nom!,
                                  password: motdepasse!,
                                  email:email!,
                                  lastname: prenom!,
                                  tr: "DEUX_A_TROIS",
                                  role: ["admin"],
                                  isActive: false);

                              APIService.register(model).then((response) {

                                setState(() {

                                  isAPIcallProcess=false;
                                });
                                if (response.data!=null ){
                                  FormHelper.showSimpleAlertDialog(
                                    context,
                                    Config.appName,
                                    "Ajout avec succès",
                                    "D\'accord",
                                        (){
                                      //  Navigator.pop(context);
                                      /* Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context,
                                '/signin', (route) => false);*/
                                      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                                          context,
                                          "/thememanagementpage",
                                              (route) => false);
                                    },
                                  );

                                }
                                else {
                                  FormHelper.showSimpleAlertDialog(
                                    context,
                                    Config.appName,
                                    response.message.message,
                                    "D\'accord",
                                        (){
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    },
                                  );
                                }
                              });
                            }*/
            print('hello');
            print('${GlobalParams.quizmodel.id}');
            print('${GlobalParams.quizmodel.quizQuestions[0].quizquestionpk.idQuestion}');
            /*for (var i=0;i<listofquizquestionsforquiz.length;i++){
              print("thabbet");
              print('réponse melowel ${ GlobalParams.quizmodel.quizQuestions[i].userAnswer}');
              print ("chouf");
            }*/
            /*for (var j=0;j<_controllers.length;j++){
              print('${_controllers[j].text}');
            }*/
            for (var j=0;j<asnwers.length;j++){
              print('${asnwers[j]}');
            }
            for (TextEditingController c in _controllers) {c.dispose();}
            for (var i=0;i<_controllers.length;i++){
              print({_controllers[i].text});
            }
          },
            btnColor: Colors.blue,
            borderColor: Colors.white,
            txtColor: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: 10,),
        ),

      ],
    );

    },
    ),
      ),
     /* SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue,),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 50,),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(50),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),

                    child:
                    // pages[_currentPage],
                    ListView.builder(

                        itemBuilder: (context,index)
                        {

                          return Column(

                            children:[
                              SizedBox(height: 10,),
                              Container(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0, bottom: 5.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.orange,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                ),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                    Text(listofquestion[index].enonce, style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16,

                                    ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                    Text(
                                        'réponse a : ${listofquestion[index].propositionA}', style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16,

                                    ),),
                                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                    Text(
                                      'réponse b : ${listofquestion[index].propositionB}', style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16,

                                    ),),
                                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                    Text(
                                      'réponse c : ${listofquestion[index].propositionC}', style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16,

                                    ),),
                                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                    Text(
                                      'réponse d : ${listofquestion[index].propositionD}', style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16,

                                    ),),
                                    SizedBox(height: 10,),

                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),

                              SizedBox(height: 10,),
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: _reponse,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "nom du quiz",
                                ),
                                validator: (value){
                                  if (value!.isNotEmpty){
                                    reponse=value;
                                    // tr="QUATRE_A_CINQ";
                                    return null;
                                  } else {
                                    return "libelle ne peut pas être vide";
                                  }
                                },
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 10,),
                            ],

                          );
                        },

                        itemCount: listofquestion.length==0 ? 0:listofquestion.length),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height:20),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Row(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        child: FormHelper.submitButton("répondre", () async{
                          //  print(id);
                          //id=value.length+1;

                          //  QuizModel quiz= QuizModel(id: id, name: _name.text, score: 0, quizCategoryEnum: tr!, quizQuestions: [], satisfactions: [], user: GlobalParams.adminModel, admin: GlobalParams.adminModel, level: GlobalParams.levelmodel, quizCategory: tr!);
                          //print(quiz.toString());
                          if(globalFormKey.currentState!.validate()){
                            test=true;

                            if (test){
                              /*  await catquizlist.then((value) {
                                modelcatquiz.idCategoryQuiz=value.length+1;
                                categoryQuizController.postCategoryQuiz
                                  (modelcatquiz, jwt!.id,modelcatquiz.idCategoryQuiz );}

                              );*/
                              // print(id);
                              print ("heeey");
                              //    questionController.postQuestion(modelLevel, GlobalParams.adminModel.id, GlobalParams.levelmodel.id);
                              var headers = {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                              };
                              var request = http.Request('POST', Uri.parse('http://'+Config.apiURL+ '/add-Quiz/${GlobalParams.jwt!.id}/${GlobalParams.levelmodel.id}'));
                              request.body = json.encode({
                                "name": _reponse.text,
                                "score": 0,
                                "quizQuestions": [],
                                "satisfactions": []
                              });
                              request.headers.addAll(headers);

                              http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

                              if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                                print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
                                FormHelper.showSimpleAlertDialog(context, "succès", "question ajouté", "D'accord",
                                        (){
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, "/chooselevelforquizpage", (route) => false);
                                    });
                              }
                              else {
                                print(response.reasonPhrase);
                              }
                            }
                            else {
                              FormHelper.showSimpleAlertDialog(context, "echec", "La tranche d'âge doit être le même que celle du thème, vérifier l'énoncé aussi", "D'accord",
                                      (){
                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                    //  Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/thememanagementpage");

                                  });
                            }
                 }
                          print('hello');
                        },
                          btnColor: Colors.orange,
                          borderColor: Colors.white,
                          txtColor: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: 10,),
                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 50,),
              /*  NumberPaginator(

                  numberPages: _numPages!,
                  onPageChange: (int index) {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentPage = index;
                    });
                  },
                  buttonSelectedForegroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                  buttonUnselectedForegroundColor: Colors.white,
                  buttonUnselectedBackgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                  buttonSelectedBackgroundColor: Colors.red,
                ),*/
              ],
            ),

        ),
      ),*/

    );
  }
}

SafeArea buildBodyContent (AsyncSnapshot <List<QuestionModel>> snapshot,
    QuestionController questionController){
 List <String> reponse=[];
  List<String> asnwers=[];
 // List<TextEditingController> _reponse=[];
  List<TextEditingController> _controllers = [];

 GlobalParams.quizmodel.quizQuestions.forEach((element) { final   quantityController =
 TextEditingController(text: element.userAnswer);
 _controllers.add(quantityController);
 });
 /* GlobalParams.quizmodel.quizQuestions.forEach((element) {//---List<Product>
    //final String answer =
    asnwers.add(answer);
  });*/
  return SafeArea(
    child:
    Scrollbar(
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      thickness: 5,
     // scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context,index)
          {
            _controllers.add(new TextEditingController());
            var cq=snapshot.data?[index];
            return Column(
              children:[
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0, bottom: 5.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Text(cq!.enonce, style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,

                      ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Text(
                        'réponse a : ${cq.propositionA}', style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,

                      ),),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Text(
                        'réponse b : ${cq.propositionB}', style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,

                      ),),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Text(
                        'réponse c : ${cq.propositionC}', style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,

                      ),),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Text(
                        'réponse d : ${cq.propositionD}', style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,

                      ),),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: _controllers[index],
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "nom du quiz",
                  ),
                  validator: (value){
                    setState(){

                    }
                    value="a";
                    if (value.isNotEmpty){
                     // _controllers.add(_controllers[index]);
                      print('${_controllers[index]}');
                      reponse[index]=value;
                      //asnwers.add(asnwers[index]);
                      // tr="QUATRE_A_CINQ";
                      return null;
                    } else {
                      return "libelle ne peut pas être vide";
                    }
                  },
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                ),

                SizedBox(height: 10,),
              ],
            );
          },
          itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ??0),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Since you have got List<TextEditingController> _controllers = [];, what's the problem here to get value from it?

Comment: kindly check again, I edited the pub and put in all the page code, I'm unable to get the controller value on user writing i to add it to the list  in order for me to work with it afterwards.